# Configure apa6 to work with the French language

Tags: babel, languages, apa6

I want to use the `apa6` style in French, so  I created `APAfrench.txt`:

```
\ProvidesFile{APAfrench.txt}[2012/02/23 v1.25 apa6 configuration for french]
\renewcommand{\rheadname}{Titre courant}
\renewcommand{\keywordname}{Mots cl'{e}s}%...
```

in vain.

How do I get the class to see the file?

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[jou,a4paper,nolmodern]{apa6}
\usepackage[american,french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}%?
\title{\'{E}tude du potentiel évoqué }
\shorttitle{Différence d'écart}
\author{Jean Dupont}
\affiliation{Nom université}
\leftheader{Dupont}

\abstract{Cette étude a permis d'examiner les premières phases d' acquisition orthographique et sémantique d'un locuteur natif anglais  monolingue apprenant des mots}

\keywords{Apprentissage d'une seconde langue, acquisition du vocabulaire}

\note{Résumé}

\authornote{Qui est cette personne ?}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Méthode}
\lipsum[1-3]


\subsection{Participants}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where and how do you read in the contents of `APAfrench.txt`?

Comment: In my system C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\apa6\config there is APAenglish.txt and other languages

Comment: Perhaps it's not a good way ? I don't know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apa6` documentation  isn't terribly user friendly in this respect.

Here's what you need to do:

In your local `texmf` directory create the following:

```
<path-to-local-texmf>/tex/latex/apa6/config
```

Place your `APAfrench.txt` there.

You should never place your own additions in the main distribution folders, since they will be overwritten with updates.

(Ideally the `apa6` class should find this file even in the same folder as your document, but unfortunately the folder structure is hard coded in the class.)

Then you need to pass the `babel` and language options with the document class (the languages go in the same order that `babel` expects them):

```
\documentclass[jou,a4paper,nolmodern,babel,american,french]{apa6}
```

You then don't need to load the `babel` package independently.

There's also an error in your `APAfrench.txt` file (accent misplaced):

```
\renewcommand{\keywordname}{Mots cl{\'e}s}
```

[image: output]